# Infinite scrollview firebase realtime database error

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

im trying to implement an infinite scroll on my listview to load 10 posts more after scroll down and must hold the last 10 on screen because i dont have a button to back to the previous list, managed to retrieve the data, but when i try to scroll down to retrieve the next 10, it crash and give this error.

```
SearchRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Normas");


    if (user != null) {
        getThreads();
        threadsListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            private int currentVisibleItemCount;
            private int currentScrollState;
            private int currentFirstVisibleItem;
            private int totalItem;
            private LinearLayout lBelow;


            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged (AbsListView view,int scrollState){
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                this.currentScrollState = scrollState;
                this.isScrollCompleted();
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll (AbsListView view,int firstVisibleItem,
                                  int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount){
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                this.currentFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
                this.currentVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;
                this.totalItem = totalItemCount;


            }

            private void isScrollCompleted () {
                if (totalItem - currentFirstVisibleItem == currentVisibleItemCount
                        && this.currentScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    /** To do code here*/
                    SearchRef.orderByKey().startAt(oldestPostId).limitToLast(10).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                MessageThread messageThread = child.getValue(MessageThread.class);
                                if (messageThread != null) {
                                    oldestPostId = child.getKey();
                                    messageThread.thread_id = child.getKey();
                                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: " + messageThread.toString());
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

                }
            };

        });
    }



public void getThreads() {
    SearchRef.limitToLast(10).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Query ordenar = mDatabase.child("Normas").orderByChild("countthreads");
            threadsList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot messageThreadSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                MessageThread messageThread = messageThreadSnapshot.getValue(MessageThread.class);
                if (messageThread != null) {
                    dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                    messageThread.thread_id = messageThreadSnapshot.getKey();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: " + messageThread.toString());
                }
                threadsList.add(messageThread);
            }
            threadsAdapter = new ThreadsAdapter(ThreadsActivity.this, R.layout.threads_listview, threadsList, ThreadsActivity.this, ordenar);
            Collections.reverse(threadsList);
            threadsListView.setAdapter(threadsAdapter);

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(ThreadsActivity.this, "ThreadsActivity: " + databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

and this is the log after crash :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must use startAt(String value), endAt(String value) or equalTo(String value) in combination with orderByKey(). Other type of values or using the version with 2 parameters is not supported

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `oldestPostId` is `null`, which is not allowed.

You'll want to check for `null` before deciding to use `oldestPostId`:

```
Query query = SearchRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(10);
if (oldestPostId != null) {
  query = query.startAt(oldestPostId);
}
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  ...
```

Btw: Firebase Realtime Database now has a [`startAfter` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#startAfter(java.lang.String)), which means you won't be retrieving the same key twice.

Comment: Hey Frank!, i edited my code with your suggest, now is not giving any error, but after scroll down, it just reload the same list.

Comment: So it sounds like `oldestPostId` is never being set. I recommend stepping through your code in a debugger, and making sure the line that you expect to set the `oldestPostId` is actually working the way you expect it to.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yeey from my side for the startAfter() method